# json encode store data in db with doubleqoutes PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I use PHP/MYSQL. My problem is when i stored data with json_encode PHP I get data with double-qoute ("").

my controller :

```
$description['content'] = $request->content;
    $description['location'] = $request->location;
    $description['area'] = $request->area;

    $id = Auth::id();
    $property = new Property();
    $property->user_id = $id;
    $property->title = $request->title;
    $property->description = json_encode($description);
    $property->status = 0;
    $property->due_date = $request->due_date;
    $property->save();
```

Data entered into the database

```
"{"content":"lorem ipsum sit dolor amet","location":"sby","area":"2"}"
```

that I expected, like this without double-qoute:

```
{"content":"lorem ipsum sit dolor amet","location":"sby","area":"2"}
```

Where my fault is located. Thank you

Comment: well, `json_encode` does return a string. what is the type of your `description` column?

Comment: in mysql i set json data type :(

Comment: could you `dd($description)` before you json_encode it and post it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in your comment you say that "in mysql i set json data type" to `description` field, cast it in your model and don't use json_encode to save it.

[Array & JSON Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)

> The array cast type is particularly useful when working with columns that are stored as serialized JSON. For example, if your database has a `JSON` or `TEXT` field type that contains serialized `JSON`, adding the array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the attribute to a `PHP array` when you access it on your Eloquent model:

```
class Property extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'description' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

> Once the cast is defined, you may access the `description` attribute and it will automatically be deserialized from `JSON` into a `PHP array`. When you set the value of the `description` attribute, the given array will automatically be serialized back into `JSON` for storage:

```
$description['content'] = $request->content;
$description['location'] = $request->location;
$description['area'] = $request->area;

$id = Auth::id();
$property = new Property();
$property->user_id = $id;
$property->title = $request->title;
$property->description = $description;
$property->status = 0;
$property->due_date = $request->due_date;
$property->save();
```

Comment: WOW it's work! just `$description` not use `json_encode($description)`, but why? Isn't `$description['key']` is array and with `json_encode` make it convert to json ?

Comment: If you add the array cast to that attribute , when you set the value, the given array will automatically be serialized back into JSON for storage.